# Switch case for array combination

Tags: php, switch-statement

I've written a switch which needs to match any combinations in the predefined array but now its matching only if all the combination from the given array is succeeded. But I want to match any combination from the array.

example : if my combination consists only `'man','cisman'` then also my combination needs to succeed and needs to return `$result = "male.png";`. But if any item otherthan the given combination needs to rejected and needs to return default case.

[Working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f086dbb072fe893be6ab551eb3115d94afccedba)

```
$menCombo = ['man','cisman','transmasculine','transman'];
$womanCombo = ['woman','ciswoman','transfeminine','transwoman'];

            switch($genderdetail) {
                case count(array_intersect($menCombo, $genderdetail)) === count(($menCombo)):
                case "man":
                case "cisman":
                case "transman":
                case "transmasculine":{
                    $result = "male.png";
                    break;
                }
                case count(array_intersect($womanCombo, $genderdetail)) === count(($womanCombo)):
                case "woman":
                case "ciswoman":
                case "transfeminine":
                case "transwoman":{
                    $result = "female.png";
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    $result = "others.png";
                    break;
                }
            }
```

Comment: 2 if else conditions should suffice actually.

Comment: I had some other comditions also thats why i use switch.

Comment: What might `$genderdetail` contain, you seem to have both arrays and singular possibilities.

Comment: @NigelRen Sometimes array and sometimes string.

Comment: Instead of using switches to tackle this problem, multiple if-then-else constructs will be more appropriate . Even if you have other other conditions (which means the conditions will be dynamic) you can still store such data into a db table and then use select statement(s) to determine whether the multiple if-then-else conditions fit your requirements.

Comment: If `$genderdetail` can be either a string or an array, I’d just force it to always be an array for this purpose so that you have a consistent algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, if `$genderdetail` isn't an array, you make it one. Now, if array difference of 2 arrays returns empty, it sure has to belong to the haystack array in comparison.

```
<?php

$genderdetail = ['man','cisman'];
$menCombo = ['man','cisman','transmasculine','transman'];
$womanCombo = ['woman','ciswoman','transfeminine','transwoman'];

$result = 'others.png';

if(!is_array($genderdetail)){
    $genderdetail = [ $genderdetail ];
}

if(empty(array_diff($genderdetail, $menCombo))){
    $result = 'male.png';
}else if(empty(array_diff($genderdetail, $womanCombo))){
    $result = 'female.png';
}

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the count condition to

case count(array_intersect($menCombo, $genderdetail)) === count(($genderdetail)):

you count the array mayches and not the long array of poszibilities. Same for the female count.